# How to differentiate $y$ with logarithmic differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am asked to find the differentiate $y$ using logarithmic differentiation  $$y=\frac{ x(x^5+1)^{1/2}}{(x-1)^{1/3}}?$$

I tried it 3 times and I got three different answer each time
Any help

Comment: Why don't you show us your attempts so that we can help spot where you may have made a mistake?

Comment: $$\ln(y) = \ln(x) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(x^5+1) -  \frac{1}{3}\ln(x-1)$$ Can you solve it from here?